# Troops not attacking Clan Castle troops

Tags: clash-of-clans

Why are my troops not attacking Clan Castle troops? I got zero stars with both attacks in our last clan war  because my wizards attacked the closest building instead of their dragon, making my hogs and barb king sitting ducks. I dropped them right under the drags, a good distance away from anything else, but they still went after buildings instead. Glitch?? Or bad luck? Anyone else see this before?

Answer (score 2):

If you place wizards while a nearby troop is being attacked by CC troops, they will engage the CC troops present. Otherwise, they attack the nearest building like any other troop.

Comment: There is exception to this, of course, that is if your troops do not have the range of the attacking troops. Wizards, for example, have a shorter range than archers, so **theoretically** archers separated with sufficient walls could hit wizards but not be hit themselves.  Another obvious example is if your troops can only attack ground targets and the attackers are from the air. Finally, troops like the giant will completely ignore clan troops unless all the defenses have been destroyed.

Comment: Well, not really. The troops will come towards the attacking CC troops to engage them, regardless of range. Ever notice why barbs can attack Archer Queens?

Answer (score 1):

Troops that targets "anything" can target CC troops. All the you have to do is when you place your troops, make them see the CC troops before the buildings, if the buildings are the nearest target, they focus on the building.

That's why so common to get the troops out of the castle, and aggro them away from towers, so that troops are killed easily.